# What happens to Ether in a contract after selfdestruct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether

When calling `selfdestruct` on a Smart contract, what happens to the Ether inside of the contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `selfdestruct()`, it takes a parameter of type `address`. Any remaining funds in the contract balance are sent to this address.